# Reading partitioned parquet in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a directory of staged data as shown below and I want to be able to read 2018 and 2019 data into one dataframe without reading them separately and unioning.

From my understand I should be able to give spark the car_data directory and apply a filter which spark would push down? when I try and do this it says the schema can't be inferred so it has to be manually defined.

Note: I need to do this without changing the name of the year folders to year=2018

1. how can I specify a schema for the below data? I've tried researching this up and I can't find it
2. how can I load the data as spark.parquet('car_data').filter('year > 2019') so that the filter is pushed down and only data for 2019-20 is loaded?
3. does anyone know what .mani files are used for?

Thanks in advance!

```
car_data
 |---2018
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet.mani
 |---2019
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet.mani
 |---2020
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet
    |---xxx.snappy.parquet.mani
```

Comment: is it possible to rename the path from `2020` to `year=2020`, or make an alternative copy?

Comment: No unfortunately, can't change the raw data. Also I wouldn't have posted the question if I could just change the name, I'm looking for an alternative, Spark says that the schema needs to be manually specified, but I can't see how any guidance on how to structure it

Comment: No unfortunately, can't change the raw dat but also I wouldn't have posted the question if I could just change the naming of the folders. I'm looking for an alternative as Spark says that the schema needs to be manually specified, but I can't see any guidance on how to structure it

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, it's not straight forward to apply a predicate, do the push down and load the relevant data. As mentioned, you are not having the column such as `year=2018`, so in this scenario you need to choose a different approach,

1. Create a function which takes an array `[2018, 2019]` and it should construct a path with the help of predicate and finally return a collection of paths.
   `Seq("/car_data/2018/", "/car_data/2019/")`
2. Pass the collection to the `spark.read.parquet(paths: String*)` which basically load all the data for the given paths. So in this case, you will get the data for `2018` and `2019` in a single Dataframe

You can make the second item as a reusable function for a convenience.

**Updated Post:**

If you want year as one of the column for the respective data set, then `iterate the collection(years) -> construct the path dynamically -> load the data -> add new column year with respective value and finally union the result`.

Comment: Thanks the problem is this method doesn't add a year column, I would like to be able to differentiate between where each row has come from

Comment: By any chance do you know what a parquet.mani file is?

Comment: @Dee Updated the post, and I haven't aware of parquet.mani file

Comment: I know I can do the above, you're not wrong but I want to avoid unioning, as there'll be a lot of df's/ files to union.

Spark says that i have to manually specify the schema if the folder name isn't year=2008,  so I need to know how in the schema I can specify that 2008 or every folder name should be put in a year column

Comment: I couldn't get the lot of df files, for eg: 2018 -> carries 100 parquet and 2019 -> carries 120 parquet files, you will load the data of 2018 as one single DF,  add a new column year set to 2018 and for 2019 single DF, add a new column year set to 2019 and finally union the two DF into single one. At the result, you have year column for each and every record in the DF.

Comment: The real data has 30+ years, each of those would need to be unioned. See what I mean?

Other datasets are partitioned by a grouping keys which results in more than 50 separate directories, see what I mean?

Comment: Spark says the schema has to be manually specified so there must be a way to specify what column the directory/ folder name belongs to

Comment: Another example is when there's two levels of partitioning i.e. year and month so inside the year folder there's a folder for each month, that's a nightmare to union e.g. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting a bit with Hive table, I realized there is a solution for you: you can [alter the table partition's location](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionLocation)

So the first thing you want to do is creating a table with all schema into it, including all possible partitions, and adding some dummy data into each partition to trigger partition creation

```sql
create table test (a string) partitioned by (date_part String);
insert into test values ('A', '2020-01-01');
-- note the current location of this partition is
-- `/apps/hive/warehouse/default.db/test/date_part=2020-01-01`
```

You now can alter partitions's location by

```sql
alter table test partition (date_part="2020-01-01")
set location "/apps/hive/warehouse/default.db/test/2020-01-01";
```

and you're all set!

```sql
select * from test where date_part="2020-01-01"
-- +----+-------------+
-- | a  |  date_part  |
-- +----+-------------+
-- | A  | 2020-01-01  |
-- +----+-------------+
```